# Let X and Y be independent Geo(0.25) distributed random variables. Let Z = X+Y . How do I compute P(Z = 3)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

this is my first question the website here. So sorry if I did something wrong.

Question:
Let X and Y be independent Geo(0.25) distributed random variables. Let Z = X+Y . How do I compute P(Z = 3)?

How do I take the sum of X and Y, and use the probability mass function to compute P(Z=3) after?

Or does does an easier method exist?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is conditioning on one of the variables. Like this:

$$
\Pr(X+Y=3) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \Pr(X+Y=3|Y=k)\Pr(Y=k).
$$

Can you take it from here?